# Onload of dynamically included static resources?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a page that I am dynamically injecting html into this page via Jquery AJAX. This html includes script/link tags to include js/css. Right now, I'm running into an issue because my `initPage()` function is running before the script that contains the `initPage()` definition has loaded.

Here's an example of my html that I am receiving from the AJAX call:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//domain.com/js/fillip.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//domain.com/js/fillip2.js'></script>
<link href='//domain.com/css/fillip.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<iframe src='//domain.com/mypage'></iframe>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        initPage();
    });
</script>
```

I need to figure out a way to run some javascript via a callback/promise after my scripts have loaded. Sometimes I will only need one script to be loaded, other times, I'll need multiple scripts loaded. Bonus points for including the ability to wait for CSS files.

### How can I wait for a dynamic set of js/css files to load before initializing the rest of my JS code?

Comment: The scripts you are trying to load, are those script under your control or are those coming from third-party sources ?

Comment: @Jas They are under my control.

Answer (score 1):

The script tags are basically processed in order they are defined in the document, assuming all the scripts are defined in the 'head' section of the document.

at the end of the document ( where you already have a function call to init ).

enclose that call under

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initPage();
}
```

Another approach can be to load the scripts via a control sequential mechanism by loading into the document one by one..

```
function loadMyJavaScript(jsPath, cb) {
  var loaded = false;

  // create a script element and add it to the head of the document.
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  // Define 3 handlers, which will perform the callback
  script.onload = successHandler;
  script.error  = errorHandler;
  script.onreadystatechange = stateHandler;


  script.src = path;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsScript);

  function successHandler() {
      if ( false == loaded ) {
           loaded = true;
           cb(path, "success"); 
      }
  }

  function errorHandler() {
      if ( false == loaded ) {
          loaded = true;
          cb(path, "error");
      }
  }

  function stateHandler() {
      var status;
      if ( false == loaded ) {
         status = script.readyState;
         if ( status === "complete" ) {
            successHandler();
         }
      }
  }
}
```

further you can call this function and assign callback as well.

```
loadMyJavaScript("http path of the script", function(path, status) {
     if ( status == "success") {
        you can load the next one or
        call your initPage();
    }

});
```

Comment: require.js can do it!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue entirely. I want to be able to ensure all of these files have loaded before I call my `initPage()` function; not just one file.